Wine not being given proper permissions?
After updating to Ubuntu 22.04 wine stopped working. I noticed some other things I did not like about Ubuntu so I went over to Debian 12. Wine still did not work. I asked in the wine forums but no one could help me. Been searching around and asking some individuals for help, but nothing worked, not even "wine managers" like PlayOnLinux or Soda would start wine(cfg).
However, I just decided to try the heinous act of running sudo winecfg and I finally got a GUI! This got me thinking that maybe the latest versions of these distros have some added security and wine is not getting the permission to draw a GUI. CLI execs worked regardless and so did winetricks.
If you are wanting to see logs, they are a mile long. You can look in that wine forum post to see the steps I have gone through and the details of the errors (even if they are from Ubuntu I got practically the same errors in Debian). If there are any logs or command lines outside of those I should try I can post their output here (or link off if also miles long).
My fstab looks like this:
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=50617566-677d-4f2d-b278-bd97d99a2cfe /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=3225b130-04f8-4190-a9e1-f3ebe5efafc8 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=4f79f2b8-b0ee-46fc-be22-2c477a42dbb3 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=54953a73-dc85-4ad8-96ae-6aa7e3bea622 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0

# Win Parts
# /dev/sda2 C:\
UUID=A03A04FA3A04CF6A /media/sda2     ntfs-3g    exec,permissions,auto  0       0
# /dev/sda8 E:\
UUID=078A40594387992A /media/sda8     ntfs-3g    exec,permissions,auto  0       0
# /dev/sdb7 H:\
UUID=18F7C0FB55E53731 /media/sdb7     ntfs-3g    exec,permissions,auto  0       0

And my .wine folder that sits in home should have the correct permissions:
drwxrwxr-x 131 edward edward   36864 Jun 24 10:13 .
drwxrwxr-x   2 edward edward    4096 Jun 24 09:53 dosdevices
drwxrwxr-x   7 edward edward    4096 Aug 17  2022 drive_c
-rw-r--r--   1 edward edward 7455694 Jun 24 09:55 system.reg
-rw-rw-r--   1 edward edward      12 Apr 14 09:34 .update-timestamp
-rw-r--r--   1 edward edward    3288 Jun 24 09:53 userdef.reg
-rw-r--r--   1 edward edward  527805 Jun 24 09:53 user.reg
-rw-rw-r--   1 edward edward     457 Nov  6  2022 winetricks.log

What's my next step from here?
Edit
Someone said that they had to use polkit to get their hyperland working and so I went looking for anything regarding that and wine. I came across this guide for Fedora and decided to try and follow the steps and well as possible considering Fedora and Debian have things in different places, and I came to a revelation.
Wine still did not work on my "owner account" but did work on the new "wineuser" account. For the heck of it I created another user without all the other steps in between and wine worked there as well. So what does my main account have from all this migration that a new user does not?

Well... Would anyone believe that the .fonts folder was the culprit? Was trying to see what conf files it was trying to access and I saw it was poking at all the fonts. Comparing with the new user I created that home folder was devoid of fonts. Chucking the fonts it loaded pretty quickly. I noticed that there were duplicate fonts in a subfolder called Library so guesses are that wine got overloaded. When did these duplicates appear I am not sure. I decided to delete the unsorted fonts and leave the Library alone and wine is running as per usual (with the delay of going through all the fonts).

My personal preference is to get wine directly from the source, rather than wait for Ubuntu or Debian to update their version. Caveat: This does require trusting wine as PPA, which I do on a home PC... but perhaps not in a commercial environment. Use Terminal for the following.

Uninstall wine as distributed by Debian.
sudo apt purge wine64
sudo apt purge wine32
sudo apt autoremove


Add wine headquarters as PPA and add its repository.
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386'
sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings 
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key 


Get the wine files.
sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/dists/bookworm/winehq-bookworm.sources 


Install wine from files.
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable 



Now test wine with a a Windows application, such as IrfanView or 7_Zip.
N.B. The first time a new version of wine is run, it takes some time to configure itself. It may request adding an extension, such as Mono for Windows DotNet apps. Be patient for that first run, and, afterwards, wine apps start quickly (faster than Snap apps, on my PC's).

Been there, done that...

Just to be sure, the latest wine-stable is version 9.0?

Yes, just look at https://www.winehq.org
